# What more LINQ operators/methods can I use to optimize my C# Collections based code?

Tags: wpf, linq, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, observablecollection

**Is there a way (using `LINQ` possibly) I can optimize the below code**. What this code does is adds, removes and updates the items in the variable `myFirstCollection` by comparing the items in variable `mySecondCollection`. Can somehow I use more LINQ methods/queries or other LINQ operators so that the `myFirstCollection` variable is compared and updated as quickly as possible.

**To add to my requirement, my `ObservableCollection` variable `myfirstCollection` is bound to the `WPF Grid` so that the additions, deletions and, updates are reflected in grid immediately with data binding.**

```
private void UpdateFirstCollection(ObservableCollection<MyDTO> myFirstCollection, IEnumerable<MyDTO> mySecondCollection)
{
//Code to add items to First Collection, how to optimize this block?
    foreach (var item in mySecondCollection.ToList())
    {
        if (!myFirstCollection.Contains(item))
        {
            myFirstCollection.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
//Code to update items from First Collection, how to optimize this block?
            var itemToUpdate = myFirstCollection.FirstOrDefault(dto => dto.ID == item.ID);
            if (itemToUpdate != null)
            {
                itemToUpdate = item;
            }
        }
    }

//Code to remove items from First Collection, how to optimize this block?
    var copy = new ObservableCollection<myDTO>(myFirstCollection);
    foreach (var item in copy.ToList())
    {
        if (!mySecondCollection.Contains(item))
        {
            myFirstCollection.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help to *Refactor* / *Improve* the above code based on any articles/links is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but since you're only adding things to `myFirstCollection` that exist in `mySecondCollection` and then removing things that don't exist in `mySecondCollection`, why don't you just clear `myFirstCollection` and add everything from `mySecondCollection`?

```
private void UpdateFirstCollection(ObservableCollection<MyDTO> myFirstCollection, IEnumerable<MyDTO> mySecondCollection)
{
    myFirstCollection.Clear();
    foreach(var item in mySecondCollection)
    {
        myFirstCollection.add(item);
    }
}
```

Please tell me if I've over-simplified this.

Comment: If I clear the myFirstCollection object, it will also clear the WPF grid bound to it and if there is any selection in grid-that selection will also be wiped.. I would need some other optimized way..!!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding any new items, removing any removed items, and updating any changed items. You are essentially replacing the entire collection.

```
myFirstCollection = mySecondCollection;
```

I know this might not be desirable from an `ObservableCollection` point of view, so instead

```
myFirstCollection.Clear();
foreach (var item in mySecondCollection)
    myFirstCollection.Add(item);
```

Comment: If I clear the myFirstCollection object, it will also clear the WPF grid bound to it and if there is any selection in grid-that selection will also be wiped.. I would need some other optimized way..!!